# Adding a footer or other partial in jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I want to add a footer to the layout that will be used on all pages of my Express app. I followed along to this related tutorial

http://www.devthought.com/code/use-jade-blocks-not-layouts/

But I seem to be missing something. Here is my code.

**layout.jade**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content

    block footer
```

**footer.jade**

```
extends layout

block footer
  footer
    ul
      li
        a(href="/team") Team
      li
        a(href="/privacy") Privacy
      p
        | company name <br> 
        | &copy; 2014, All Rights Reserved
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently it works to use includes. I added it to my layout since it will be the same across all pages.

**layout.jade**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content

    include footer
```

Comment: commenting from the future. thanks for coming back to finish the story